# js click element where inside in a div

Tags: javascript, click, target

I have a Slider, and want to stop it. Now I make like this: If the classname === 'slider' then stop.

But I work with e.target.classList. So if I click on Slider, then I get the classname 'e-target-another-class'. But I want that I click within a div where the name is slider then stop. I hope you have understand my

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="e-target-new-class">
    <div class="e-target-anohter-class">
       slider
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing a `</div>` - typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the event listener to the desired `.slider` Element.
And *"don't"* use Event.target (unless you really know what you're doing) - **use [**Event.currentTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead**.

In your case the currentTarget will always be the desired `.slider` wrapper element

```js
function stopSlider(ev) {

  const delegator = ev.currentTarget; // This is what you want!
  const target = ev.target;
  
  console.clear(); console.log(`DELEGATOR: ${[...delegator.classList]}
TARGET: ${[...target.classList]}`);
}

const ELS_slider = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");
ELS_slider.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", stopSlider));
```

```css
[class^=slider] {outline: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  SLIDER
  <div class="slider-slides">
    ALL SLIDES
    <div class="slider-slide">
      SINGLE SLIDE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```